# MAMP localhost Symfony mail function

Tags: symfony, email, mamp, swiftmailer

I installed MAMP and symfony3.
I have swiftmailer configured like this:

```
...
mailer_transport: mail
mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
mailer_user: null
mailer_password: null
...
```

Symfony still want to connect to the SMTP server of the email domain configured as the sender instead of using the native email php function()

Can anyone tell me why?

Answer (score 0):

Have you cleared your cache ? Your parameters changes are not applied without a `cache:clear`, even in dev environment.

Comment: Yes! I also tried to use simply --> mail("myemail@email...","subject","text"); <-- and php tell me that mail is sent but nothing is arriving. my firewall said that terminal want to connect to smtp 8.8.8.8 and then to mx.mydomain.com.

Comment: it seems that you use a mac (me too). you have to configure your mac. you can do that with the server application from apple. But easier will be if you create a smtp account (some where you like ,e.g. google) and send your test mails over that account.

Comment: Something like sparkpost is really easy to use